# What is LightGBM's support for missing labels

Tags: machine-learning, lightgbm

We have a dataset where some of the labels are missing.  This just came to our knowledge recently and we have removed those rows.  This got me thinking as to how this ever worked?  It doesn't seem to make sense to give a GBM an example without a label.

Can anyone shed some light (pun intended) on how LightGBM handles rows where the label is missing?

Thanks